# Why isn't my variable available inside the scope of an AngularJS promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write promises to take from back-end some data. But function end() don't see my variable witch contains this data. What I'm doing wrong, and how to return overlappingProjects variable?

Console.log(1 and 2) shows massive with data but console.log(4) already have empty object.

```
this.checkSingleInvitation = function(invitation) {
    console.log('Оверлап сингл');
    var dtoArray = [];
    var overlappingProjects = {};

    InvitationService.acceptedProjects.models.forEach(function(accepted) {
        if(!(dateHelper.parseDate(accepted.dt_from) > dateHelper.parseDate(invitation.dt_to) || dateHelper.parseDate(accepted.dt_to) < dateHelper.parseDate(invitation.dt_from))) {
            var dto = {
                target: invitation.project_has_musicians_id,
                goal: accepted.project_id
            };
            dtoArray.push(dto);
        }
    });

    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach(dtoArray, (function(dto) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var overlappingProjects = {};
        //async fun
        InvitationService.checkOverlapping(dto)
            .before(function() {
                progressBars.progressbar.requestsInProgress++;
            })
            .success(function(data) {
                // TODO: overlappingProjects - ???
                if(Object.keys(data).length) {
                    console.log('1');
                    console.log(data);
                    overlappingProjects = data;
                    console.log(overlappingProjects);
                }
                console.log('2');
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            })
            .finally(function() {
                progressBars.progressbar.requestsInProgress--;
            });
        promises.push(deferred.promise);
    }));
    $q.all(promises).then(console.log(promises)).then(
        end()
    );

    function end() {
        console.log('4');
        console.log(overlappingProjects);
        return overlappingProjects;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to push `InvitationService.checkOverlapping(dto)` into the promises array. And wait for that to resolve with `all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to twice variable(`overlappingProjects`) declaration, you call `end` function immediately instead of pass it as callback:

> ```
> $q.all(promises).then(console.log(promises)).then(
>     end()
> );
> ```

Should be:

```
$q.all(promises)
  .then(() => console.log(promises)) // may be .then(results => console.log(results)) ?
  .then(end);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are defining `overlappingProjects` twice.
Remove the second definition:

```
  angular.forEach(dtoArray, (function(dto) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var overlappingProjects = {};  //  <-- remove this line
```